# How do you say "I have constant value" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I'm mostly struggling with the "I have" portion as well as the actual layout of the sentence in Latin.

Even though every website seems to have a different Latin equivalent for English words, and many sites don't recognize a certain word as Latin when others do, I've made it this far:

I = Ego

Have = habeo or habere (not entirely sure what the difference is)

Constant = constans

Value (as in self-worth or intrinsic value) = virtus or pretium

Literally, that leaves me with my preferred translation of "Ego habeo constans virtus".

I think this would be phrased differently and with fewer words in an actual Latin sentence though. Depending on the site or tool I use, it leaves off either the "ego" "or habeo/habere". It sometimes also flips the location of the words just like how Spanish has adjectives after nouns. So I'm assuming the actual latin will look different from my literal, word-for-word translation (and hopefully shorter).

If someone were saying in Latin "I have constant value", what would it look like? The word constant needs to be in there and not some synonym because it's a critical piece of an eBook I'm incorporating this into.

It would be amazing if you could give the most accurate translation as well as a grammatical proof or explanation so I can have confidence in it. Variants of the latin sentence would also be helpful if you so desire.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the site! What sort of value is the person in question portraying? For example, if they were possessing manly virtue, virtus is a great word. But if their virtue was working a lot, the translation would be very different.

Comment: @Nickimite value as in self-worth. The ebook is focused on how if we truly recognized our intrinsic self-worth we would be set free from using others to convince us that we have value. So the thesis is that individuals have unwavering, intrinsic, limitless worth/value. 
I summarize all of that by stating all we need to believe is "I have constant value". 
Hopefully that is enough context to explain the intent behind the word "value".
I saw that virtus had many "virtuous" type definitions, but I also saw that it had definitions that pertained to worth, and I liked the extra connotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt at translation was quite close to a grammatical sentence. But in Latin, one needs to consider declension and conjugation.

Ego = I

- This is correct. Normally, Latin drops pronouns like this, but since the intended meaning juxtaposes oneself with everyone else, this is a good word.

habeo = have

- This is the 1st person, singular, present, active, indicative form of habere. This form works here because it agrees with the person doing the action (I) and declares with certainty what the world truly is.

constans virtus ~~ constant value

- If these are the words you choose, you want the form that shows they are the object of the sentence. These forms are constantem and virtutem.

---

Putting all these words together into a sentence, you get:

- Ego constantem virtutem habeo.

Alternatively, if you want to emphasize that one's virtue is *enduring* (and not transient), you could say:

- Ego virtutem habeo constantem.

Comment: *Constans* is a participle. Could you do something more directly with *constare*?

Comment: According to Whitaker's Words, it is also a simple adjective.

Answer (score 5):

I notice you chose a curiously mathematical wording. In light of this, you could also use a mathematical expression in Latin, and say:

> Valorem constantem habeo.

(Personally, I'd lose the *ego*.) This is not classical Latin; in fact, the ancient Romans did not know the word *valor*. But this is the sort of Latin that Euler or Gauss wrote.

---

There is actually a Latin word meaning “to have value,” *valere*. But when applied to people, it usually means “to be fine, in good health, strong,” also known from the Latin farewell greeting *vale*, which essentially means “be well.” In fact, most other words in the value/valour/valid/etc family derive from this verb (which is also the reason why a more common term for “farewell greeting” would be “valediction”!). But in itself it would too easily be misunderstood in this context.

Answer (score 4):

In ancient times, the words *dignitas* or *honor* were used when speaking of the value of a person. The word *is* can often be eliminated in Latin, so I would translate it as:

> Constans dignitas mea

"Constant is my value," giving emphasis to the constancy of it. Alternatively, it could be translated as:

> Constans honor meus

Answer (score 3):

To add another option, I think it's more idiomatic Latin to use the verb *constāre* directly.

> Valor meus constat.
>   *My value is constant.*

(Or, equivalently, "my value remains fixed" or "my value doesn't change".)

Answer (score 1):

*Valorem immutabilem habeo*.

*Immutabilis* is a less general word than *constans*, which has many meanings.

Answer (score 0):

To me, virtus seems to be a very male-oriented word. Perhaps a different substitution like potens omnium would be better? This is how I personally would translate the phrase.

- Ego sum potens omnium
- "I am capable of all things" or more idiomatically in English, "I can do anything"